# Summary statistics for weighted values using the ANESRAKE package in R

Tags: r, survey, weighted

I have created weighted data with my survey using the `anesrake` and `weights` package. However, I am not sure how to use the weights afterwards, beside `wpct` function in the package. How can I compute say descriptive stats and integrate the weighted data with other functions/packages?

Reproducible data from the `anesrake` package:

```
data("anes04")
anes04$caseid <- 1:length(anes04$age)
anes04$agecats <- cut(anes04$age, c(0, 25,35,45,55,65,99))
levels(anes04$agecats) <- c("age1824", "age2534", "age3544",
"age4554", "age5564", "age6599")
marriedtarget <- c(.4, .6)
agetarg <- c(.10, .15, .17, .23, .22, .13)
names(agetarg) <- c("age1824", "age2534", "age3544",
"age4554", "age5564", "age6599")
targets <- list(marriedtarget, agetarg)
names(targets) <- c("married", "agecats")
outsave <- anesrake(targets, anes04, caseid=anes04$caseid,
verbose=TRUE)
caseweights <- data.frame(cases=outsave$caseid, weights=outsave$weightvec)
```

This will give me a new vector with weights for the dataframe. So, my question is, how can I analyze the data know? How can I incorporate these weights with summary statistics?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible exmaple

Comment: Sorry, I don't have REPEX, but I figured I don't because it's a question about a specific package/method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could supply the weights as the `weights=` argument to `survey::svydesign`.  Ideally, you'd do the raking in the survey package so that you could take account of the variance reductions from raking, but it's pretty standard (at least in public-use data) to analyse raked weights as if they were just sampling weights.

Or, if the raking specification you ended up with was simple enough to reproduce in `survey::rake` or `survey::calibrate`,  you could redo the raking in the survey package.

The reason for using the survey package is the very wide range of other analyses it allows (and even more with `svyVGAM`).